# Out of Range error when creating thumbnails of MXDs

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy

I am tryting to create thumbnails of all the mxd's in a directory but no mater how high I set the value of the "While" loop it gives me an "Index out of range" error...

Also can I get it to look at subdirectories as well?

best,

```
#Make thumbnails from all mxd's in current directory

import arcpy, glob, os, sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import mapping
env.overwriteOutput = True

#path = sys.argv[1] # for using in toolset, use directory parameter
path = os.getcwd() # Script in same directory as files being processed
mxdList = glob.glob(path + "\*.mxd")
env.workspace = path
x=0

print 'Reading mxd files from ' + path

mxd_List = glob.glob('*.mxd')
count_Mapdocs = len(mxd_List)
print mxd_List,count_Mapdocs

while x < 50:
 mapDocs=mxd_List[x]
 mapDoc=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mapDocs)
 framesList=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mapDoc)
 mapDoc.activeView=framesList[x]
 mapDoc.makeThumbnail()
 mapDoc.save()
 print "Created thumbnail for " + mxd_List[x]
 print "x= "+ str(x)
 x=x+1
 print "x updated =" + str(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
while x < 50:
 mapDocs=mxd_list[x]
 ...
```

What your are trying to do here is index ([x]) objects that do not exist.  For instance your statement:

```
mxd_List = glob.glob('*.mxd')
```

Is returning a list of mxd's in a directory, there may be 0 (zero) or many objects in this list.  If there is only one, and you are trying to specify 50 then you will get an *Index Out of Range* exception.

You need to do the following (which I noticed in your code you've already got a value for this:

```
while x < count_Mapdocs:
  mapDocs=mxd_list[x]
  ...
```

This will fix your error.

Iterating through a directory structure is a little more involved (at least its a step up in your learning curve). You will import the os library, and use it to specify the directories of your input path:

```
import arcpy, glob, os, sys
from arcpy import env
from arcpy import mapping
env.overwriteOutput = True
your_path = "c:/"

# Check if you path exists
if os.path.exists(your_path):
  # lists all the contents of your path directories and files
  dir_list = os.listdir(your_path) 

  # iterate through your list
  for dir in dir_list:
    # append the name of the object to your_path
    dir_path = os.path.join(your_path, dir)

    # check to make sure the current list object is a directory
    if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
      print dir_path
      #
      # Your code goes here
      #
      mxd_List = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.mxd'))
      count_Mapdocs = len(mxd_List)
      while x < count_Mapdocs:
        mapDocs=mxd_List[x]
        ...
```

Hope this helps.